# How to get the list of all the packages with their versions from Artifacts/Nuget Feed in Azure Devops using C#?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-artifacts, azure-devops-artifacts

I want to get the list of the packages present in Azure DevOps Artifacts with their latest versions. Can I use a Personal Access token to get this list using C#?

I am not able to find a way to get this through the C# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the [Artifact Details API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact-details/get-packages?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) is what you're looking for?

Otherwise, you might include the [`dotnet list package`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-list-package) command in your build pipeline to be able to have a look at that, but that sounds like more manual labor than you're looking to do :)

Comment: How to add Personal Access Token in this API call? Should I add it as a header when making the api call? Because I am getting unauthorized error. @WerkmanW

Comment: Depends how you're making the call to the API but try and look at this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokens/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=powershell